# Prevent Delete Attachment by URL or When Submit

Tags: posts, plugin-development, customization, uploads, attachments

This code is working, which prevent being deleted by specific title:

```
add_action( 'delete_attachment', 'check_relations' ); 

    function check_relations( $post_id ){

     if(get_the_title( $post_id )=='ver'){
     wp_die("Sorry, you can't delete this.");

    } }
```

But I want to prevent an  attachment being deleted when the user upload it from a specific url (verification page) example:
https://www.example.com/dashboard/settings/verification/

Does anyone know? Thanks.

Also pretty good if can prevent attachment being deleted when submit. Thank you.